# How to multiply voltage of a pulsating positive only source?

Tags: high-voltage, multiplier

Total newbie here.

I'm trying to multiply the voltage of a positive only pulsating source. It variates from 0v to 500v.

All voltage multipliers I found explain how they work with a AC source, varying from +V to -V. I can't get my head around an schematic for +V to 0V.

Comment: When you say "multiply the voltage", do you literally mean \$V_\text{out} = k \times V_\text{in}\$, for some constant \$k\$? If so, you'll need an *operational amplifier*. Though I doubt you'll find one working at 500V.

Comment: I mean in the classic diode-capacitor cascade way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dc blocking capacitor (large, but best size will vary with frequency) to obtain an alternating current from your pulsed, single-direction current source.

Answer (score 0):

Don't get so hung up on the notion or importance of 0V. It's just a reference point that we give a circuit, usually designated for a specific voltage (for instance at the negative connection to a battery).

For mains, 0V is the reference voltage - so an AC signal varies around that reference. Let's say you have an input consisting of a ground reference that we call 0V. The other lead swings around this reference \$\pm 250\text{V}\$. If I put a battery of \$250\text{V}\$ connecting *the positive lead* to the ground, my negative pole will be at \$-250\text{V}\$. And now, the **difference** between my negative pole and the swinging voltage will be \$250\;\text{V} \pm 250\;\text{V}\$, or from \$0\;\text{V}\$ to \$500\;\text{V}\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdK0Zw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here's an analogy: You are in a tall building next to a 50 meter diameter ferris wheel. You are on the fifth floor (at 25 meters), and the center of the wheel is also at 25 meters. People on the wheel now spin up and down \$\pm 25\$ meters relative to you. However, when you take the stairs down to ground level, now they spin from 0 meters to 50 meters.

Comment: All this is true, but it doesn't answer the question.